# Close element that is visible with slideToggle from another button?

Tags: jquery

I have an element named `#map-menu-container` Inside this I have some buttons that are visible after you click on the slideToggle button named `#map-menu-container-btn`. With this button I open and close the container with the buttons.

But I wonder if it's possible in some way to slideToggle back(close) the container with all the buttons when a button is clicked? The buttons could all have some class that detects the click, but how could this then slide back the container?

The code below is the jQuery to handle the container.

```
    //Map menu
$("#map-menu-container-btn").click(function(){
    $("#map-menu-container").slideToggle("fast", function() {
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            $("p#text-map-menu").text("hide map menu");
        } else {
            $("p#text-map-menu").text("show map menu");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would just put the toggle in a separate function and call it from both click events.

```
(function($){
    var $mapMenuContainer = $("#map-menu-container");

    var toggleMenuContainer = function(){
        $mapMenuContainer.slideToggle("fast", function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $("p#text-map-menu").text("hide map menu");
                //$("#map-menu-icon").attr("src","/images/bilderLayout/map-menu-btn-up.png")
            } else {
                $("p#text-map-menu").text("show map menu"); 
                //$("#map-menu-icon").attr("src","/images/bilderLayout/map-menu-btn-down.png")  
            }
        });
    };

    $("#map-menu-container-btn, .buttons").click(toggleMenuContainer);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't think you'll need to create the vars or list multiple `.on` functions.

You can replace the last lines with: 
`$("#map-menu-container-btn, .buttons").click(toggleMenuContainer);`

And instead of creating the `$mapMenuContainer` variable, just reference the class in the `toggleMenuContainer` function
`var toggleMenuContainer = function(){
        $("#map-menu-container").slideToggle...`

Comment: Updated the click event, but the container gets cached so that jQuery doesn't have to traverse the dom to look for the container every time a button is clicked (unless I misunderstood what you were saying)

Comment: Well I just learned something new. Thanks for that tip, didn't know about jQuery caching.

Comment: That's cool, learning is always a good thing! That is also why I cached the buttons, but in this case it doesn't matter as we are only referencing the buttons once. I generally cache all my selectors anyway, but in this case I don't believe it would matter.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer! But I didn't thought it should be that complicated! I will try the code later.